# Poetry fails whenever I try to run cicd in GitHub Actions

Tags: pipeline, github-actions, python-poetry, cicd

I'm facing a problem with Poetry and GitHub actions in the last days. Maybe because Poetry has an updated version.

**Information**

- Poetry version 1.1.9

I'm using the following `.yml` file for the CICD

```yaml
jobs:
  execute-linters:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Pyton 3.9
        uses: actions/setup-python@v2
        with:
          python-version: 3.9

      - name: Poetry
        uses: Gr1N/setup-poetry@v7
      
      - name: Dependencies
        run: poetry install
...
```

Whenever it runs, during the `Dependencies` job, it fails and I've got the following error

```
• Installing py (1.10.0)

  EnvCommandError

  Command ['/home/runner/work/ds-gdem-pvso/ds-gdem-pvso/.venv/bin/pip', 'install', '--no-deps', '/home/runner/.cache/pypoetry/artifacts/c8/3a/b1/6d8182aff6a688801f32ca473f2ba55ecb83446a84cf3d1afad18800e0/ibm_db-3.0.4.tar.gz'] errored with the following return code 1, and output: 
  Processing /home/runner/.cache/pypoetry/artifacts/c8/3a/b1/6d8182aff6a688801f32ca473f2ba55ecb83446a84cf3d1afad18800e0/ibm_db-3.0.4.tar.gz
      ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
       command: /home/runner/work/ds-gdem-pvso/ds-gdem-pvso/.venv/bin/python -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-req-build-c_nfk704/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-req-build-c_nfk704/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-9hi5cw5y
           cwd: /tmp/pip-req-build-c_nfk704/
      Complete output (3 lines):
      Detected 64-bit Python
      Downloading https://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/data/db2/drivers/odbc_cli/linuxx64_odbc_cli.tar.gz
      error in ibm_db setup command: use_2to3 is invalid.
      ----------------------------------------
  WARNING: Discarding file:///home/runner/.cache/pypoetry/artifacts/c8/3a/b1/6d8182aff6a688801f32ca473f2ba55ecb83446a84cf3d1afad18800e0/ibm_db-3.0.4.tar.gz. Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
  

  at ~/.local/share/pypoetry/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/poetry/utils/env.py:1180 in _run
      1176│                 output = subprocess.check_output(
      1177│                     cmd, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, **kwargs
      1178│                 )
      1179│         except CalledProcessError as e:
    → 1180│             raise EnvCommandError(e, input=input_)
      1181│ 
      1182│         return decode(output)
      1183│ 
      1184│     def execute(self, bin, *args, **kwargs):

  • Installing pyarrow (4.0.1)
  • Installing regex (2021.8.28)
  • Installing scikit-learn (0.24.2)
  • Installing toml (0.10.2)
  • Installing tomli (1.2.1)
  • Installing tqdm (4.62.3)
  • Installing typing-inspect (0.7.1)
  • Installing wrapt (1.12.1)
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

**Attempts**

At first I was using the `Gr1N/setup-poetry@v4` and I notice that it was outdated. I've tried to update it to `Gr1N/setup-poetry@v7`, but didn't work.

I also received this `Warning: The lock file is not up to date with the latest changes in pyproject.toml. You may be getting outdated dependencies. Run update to update them.`. I've tried to delete `poetry.lock` and run `poetry update` to generate a new one, no success at all.

Could anyone try to help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can pin the `poetry` version [link](https://github.com/Gr1N/setup-poetry) to what you have in your local environment (use `poetry --version`) to fix that.

```yaml
  - uses: Gr1N/setup-poetry@v7
    with:
      poetry-version: 1.1.7
```

It is always a good practice to pin down your libraries and make sure your local environment is as similar as possible to the deployment environment.